# Django always tries to establish SSL connection with localhost

Tags: django, google-chrome, ssl, heroku, localhost

After setting `DEBUG = False`, and `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` and deploying a version on my app to the server, I wish now to develop further locally.  The problem is, I think at one point I forgot to remove the `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` from settings.py, and I ran the local dev server with `heroku local`.  My local browser always tries not to connect to localhost with SSL, so it just hangs.

I tried removing the site-specific cookies for localhost in the browser settings (Chrome) but localhost now still always tries to establish an SSL connection.

I am trying just to get back to using a non-SSL local connection for development.  Any Ideas?

Django version 1.10.2
Heroku

Thanks

**EDIT**

Seems if I clear ALL the cache and cookies and restart the browser then it will not ask for SSL again.  So it seems to be a browser problem.  Anyway if anyone has an idea of how to accomplish this without having to clear all the data in Chrome, that would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have learned a better way to handle this situation.  I have set up some code to automatically sense if the software is running on the local environment or the cloud production environment, like this:

```
if os.environ.get('LOCAL'):
    DEBUG = True
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
else:
    DEBUG = False
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

Of course you have to take care of setting up the `environ` object, which happens automatically in heroku.

Answer (score 2):

I am using custom settings both for local (development) and production environments.

For instance:
**myproject/settings/dev.py**

```
DEBUG = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
...
```

**myproject/settings/production.py**

```
DEBUG = False
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
...
```

And then I specify the settings I want to use. On **localhost** like this:
`python myproject/manage.py runserver --settings=settings.dev`

and for production using the Heroku **Procfile**:
`web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi.production --log-file -`

Content of **myproject/wsgi/production.py** is:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings.production")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

If you use `heroku local` for your local development, you can create similar **Procfile.local** with local wsgi file.